# Is setting the DataSource property of two combo boxes in one line known to cause issues?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

The following line of code seems to be causing a bug

```cs
comboBoxLunch1.DataSource = comboBoxLunch2.DataSource = GrabLunchFromSQL();
```

replacing it with the following removes the bug

```cs
comboBoxLunch1.DataSource = GrabLunchFromSQL();
comboBoxLunch2.DataSource = GrabLunchFromSQL();
```

Said bug is that changing the selected item in one combo box will change it in another. Is this a known issue with a known explanation? Nothing in the documentation for `DataSource` suggests such an issue to me and I don't see why the choice of data source would relate to how the entries are stored in memory.

Comment: GrabLunchFromSQL presumably creates a new result of whatever type with every call. So second code uses independent results per ComboBox while the first does not.

Comment: @Ralf The return value is a DataTable. Does that make the explanation of what's causing the issue completely obvious?

Comment: The first line of code is using the same DataTable for both ComboBoxes, so yes, setting the selected item on one will cause the other to do the same.  The second line uses two independent DataTables.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @LarsTech Agreed. That appears to be all issues settled. Thank you both.